# How to create a table from data that I obtained by a query

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to create a table with the data that I obtained from the query.

```
select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS BloqueConcreto 
from dbo.FICH_3_3$ 
where SIGPAREDEX ='BCO' 

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS Ripios 
from dbo.FICH_3_3$ 
where SIGPAREDEX ='RIP'

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS Minifalda 
from dbo.FICH_3_3$ 
where SIGPAREDEX ='MIN'

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As MaderaAcepillada 
from dbo.FICH_3_3$ 
where SIGPAREDEX ='MAD'

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS LosetasConcreto from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'CPR'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As MaderaRustica from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'MAR'

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As LadrilloCuarteron from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'LAC'
select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS LaminasMetalicas from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'MET'

select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As Plywood from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'PLY'
select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As BloqueDeBarro from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'BBA'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As Katrinite from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'KAD'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As LaminaFibroCemento from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'LFC'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As ConcretoMonolitico from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'CMO'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As PiedraCantera from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'PCA'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As Adobe from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'ADO'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As Convitec from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'COV'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As Gypsum from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'GYP'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As PanelFerroCemento from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'PFC'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As PiedraBolon from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'PRC'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As SinInformacion from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'SIN'

Select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) As LaminasTroqueladas from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX = 'LTR'
```

I tried with views using:

```
SELECT SIGPAREDEX ,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM View1 ) THEN '1' 

  END AS [LTR],
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM View2 ) THEN '1'

    END AS [SIN]

    From dbo.FICH_3_3$
```

But this is not exactly what I want, I need to obtained something like this:

```
Bloque concreto   11698  
Ripios            29..
Minifalda          3109
Plywood            a value
```

Everything in one table

Help me as soon as possible please

Regards

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: from the "dbo." you can deduct she's using MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer as pseudo code.
You need to use Union all as give names to subqueries.
These names have to be the same, because you are building one table.

```
select 'YourDataTile' as Title,(select count(YOURCOL) as Value from YOURTABLE ) Value
union all
select 'YourOtherDataTile' as Title,(select count(YOUROTHERCOL) as Vvalue from YOUROTHERTABLETABLE ) Value
```

Here is the begining of your example

```
SELECT 'BloqueConcreto' as Title, (select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS BloqueConcreto from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX ='BCO') Value
union all
SELECT 'Ripios ' as Title, (select COUNT (SIGPAREDEX) AS Ripios from dbo.FICH_3_3$ where SIGPAREDEX ='RIP') Value
```

just add

```
union all select ....
```

for all your queries